# react-router jumping from IndexRoute when rendering child route

Tags: reactjs

I have this router in my app:

```
<Router history={ browserHistory } >
    <Route path="/" component={Header}>
        <IndexRoute component={Main} />
        <Route path="view" component={ViewItem} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Whenever I'm trying to render the /view it renders the indexroute for a split second and then renders the /view completely. Note: I'm using server side rendering for react-router.

Thanks

EDIT:

Server side code:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error.message)
        } else if (redirectLocation) {
            res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
        } else if (renderProps) {
            // You can also check renderProps.components or renderProps.routes for
            // your "not found" component or route respectively, and send a 404 as
            // below, if you're using a catch-all route.

            const store = createStore(reducers);

            const html = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
                </Provider>
            )

            const initialState = store.getState();
            res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html, initialState));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not found')
        }
    })
});


function renderFullPage(html, initialState) {
    return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="reactbody"><div>${html}</div></div>
        <script>
            window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
          </script>
        <script src="../bin/app.bundle.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://www.atlasestateagents.co.uk/javascript/tether.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
    `
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the leading `/` from the view path e.g. `path="view"`

Comment: Sorry I tried that already :) It's same

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using `react-router`'s `match` function to render the route on the server? I assume you're using `<RouterContext/>` on the server?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Added in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. I have to use req.originalUrl as req.url is always returning "/". I just searched the Express 4.x api and apparently req.url doesn't even exists anymore.

Hope it helps in future for someone.

Comment: Actually express just wraps node's request, `req.url` is definitely still supported (see [express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) and [node](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) docs). Very interesting that changing `.url` to `.originalUrl` would make a difference if you're not rewriting `req.url`. Also interesting that `.originalUrl` could be anything but `/` in a route that only matches on `/`. Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Your route is only matching on '/' by the looks of it, not '*'. This should be `router.get('*', function (req, res) {`. Since this will be a 'catch all' route, it must come after every other route.

But... if that is your only route, then trying to get `/view` I would have thought would return 'cannot find /view', so there must be something else going on to handle that.

On a side note, you probably don't want to createStore on *every* network request, you can move that line outside `router.get`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but that wasn't the solution. I am answering it :)